Behavior of total kinetic energy operator under local rotations
Consider the space of square integrable complex functions $f(x_1,\ldots,x_n)$ on $\mathbb{R}^{3n}$ taking $n$ three-dimensional vectors $x_i$ as arguments.
Assign to each vector $x_i$ a mass $m_i$ and define the total mass
$$
m_o = \sum_{j=1} m_j
$$
and the center of mass
$$
x_o = \frac{\sum_{j=1}^n m_j x_j}{m_o}\,\,\,.
$$
We define also a total kinetic energy operator
$$
t_o=\sum_{j=1}^n t_j
$$
where
$$
t_j = \frac{1}{m_j}\nabla^2_j
$$
where $\nabla^2_j f$ is the Laplacian of a function $f$ with respect to the argument $x_j$.
We can define an operator $O$ affecting a collective rotation $x_i \to x_i' = R x_i$ of all the vectors $x_i$, where $R \in O(3)$ is a proper or improper rotation, i.e.
$$
Of(x_1,\ldots,x_n) = f(Rx_1,\ldots,Rx_n)
$$
and one can notably show that $O$ commutes with $t_o$.
However we can also imagine, given a operation $R \in O(3)$, an operator $O'$ affecting a "local" rotation
$$
x_i \to R\left(x_i - x_o\right) + x_o\,\,\,.
$$
My first question is: would $O'$ also commute with $t_o$?
Finally, we can also imagine an operator $O''$ affecting the coordinate transformation:
$$
x_i \to R'(x_o) (x_i - x_o) + x_o
$$
where $R' : \mathbb{R}^3 \to O(3)$ is some map taking a center of mass $x_o$ and return a proper or improper rotation $R'(x_o)$.
Does $O''$ commute with $t_o$ for any $R'$?
I would not think so, especially since we have no conditions on the map $R'$.

I was able to verify via "brute force" that $O'$ does in fact commute with $T$.
I also found a counter-example demonstrating that there are operators $O''$ which do not commute with $T$.
I provide here a sketch of the calculations.
In general for an operator $O$ affecting a coordinate transformation $y_i 
\to y_i'(\ldots,y_j,\ldots)$, i.e. an operator $O$ acting on a function $f(\ldots,y_j,\ldots)$ so that $Of(\ldots,y_i,\ldots)=f\left(\ldots,y_i'\left(\ldots,y_j,\ldots\right),\ldots\right)$ then we have
$$
\partial_i O = \left(\partial_i y'_j\right) O \partial_j
\tag{1}
$$
where $\partial_i \equiv \frac{\partial}{\partial y_i}$ is an operator acting on functions in the obvious way.
In our case we have an operator $O'$ affecting a coordinate transformation
$$
x_{\alpha i} \to x_{\alpha i}'\left(\ldots,x_{\beta j},\ldots\right)=\sum_{j=1}^3 R_{ij}\left(x_{\alpha j} - x^o_j\right) - x^o_i
$$
where $x_{\alpha i}$ denotes component $i$ of particle $\alpha$, $R_{ij}$ is a $3 \times 3$ orthogonal matrix, and
$$
x^o_i = \frac{\sum_{\alpha=1}^n m_\alpha x_{\alpha i}}{\sum_{\alpha=1}^n m_\alpha}
$$
is component $i$ of the center of mass.
Defining $m\equiv\sum_{\alpha=1}^n m_\alpha$, we have then from Eq. (1)
$$
[\partial_{\alpha i},O'] = O' \left(R_{ji} - \delta_{ij}\right)\left(\delta_{\alpha \beta} - m_\alpha / m\right)\partial_{\beta j}\equiv O' M^{\alpha i}_{\beta j} \partial_{\beta j}
$$
with implicit summing over repeating indices.
From $[A^2,B] = A[A,B] + [A,B]A$ we obtain
$$
[\partial_{\alpha i}^2,O'] = O'\left(2 M^{\alpha i}_{\beta j} \partial_{\alpha i}\partial_{\beta j} + M^{\alpha i}_{\gamma k}M^{\alpha i}_{\beta j}\partial_{\gamma k}\partial_{\beta j}\right)
$$
By carefully plugging expanding out all the terms and applying the equations $\sum_{\alpha=1}^n m_\alpha = m$ and $\sum_{k=1}^3 R_{ik} R_{jk} = \delta_{ij}$ one can show that indeed
$$
[T,O']=[\sum_{\alpha=1}^n m_\alpha^{-1} \sum_{i=1}^3 \partial^2_{\alpha i},O'] = 0
$$
A perhaps cleaner approach requires first defining the coordinate system $x^o_i,\Delta x_{2i},\ldots,\Delta x_{ni}$ where the $x^o_i$ for $i=1,2,3$ are the same center of mass coordinates while the $\Delta x_{\alpha i} \equiv x_{\alpha i} - x^o_i$ for $\alpha=2,\ldots,n$ are the relative coordinates.
One can show that
$$
T = \frac{1}{m}\sum_{i=1}^3 \tilde{\partial}^2_{oi} - \frac{1}{m}\sum_{\alpha,\beta=2}^n \sum_{i=1}^3 \tilde{\partial}_{\alpha i} \tilde{\partial}_{\beta i} + \sum_{\alpha=2}^n \frac{1}{m_\alpha} \sum_{i=1}^3 \tilde{\partial}_{\alpha i}^2
$$
where the $\tilde{\partial}$ denotes a partial derivative with respect to the new coordinate system.
Specifically we have $\tilde{\partial}_{oi} \equiv \frac{\partial}{\partial x^o_i}$ and $\tilde{\partial}_{\alpha i} \equiv \frac{\partial}{\partial \Delta x_{\alpha i}}$.
It is more straightforward to show that $O'$ commutes with $T$ in these coordinates.
If one generalizes the operator $O'$ to an operator $O''$ affecting "local rotations" corresponding to a coordinate transformation
$$
x_{\alpha i} \to x'_{\alpha i} = R'\left( x^o \right)_{ij} \left( x_{\alpha j} - x^o_j \right) - x^o_i
$$
where the rotation matrix $R'_{ij}$ is a function of the center of mass coordinates $x^o_i$, then in general we have $[T,O''] \neq 0$.
I derived a rather complicated expression for the commutator which I am not sure is fully simplified.
Instead I will give an example of a function $f$ of $n=2$ particles and a local rotation function $R'_{ij}\left(x^o\right)$ where the $[T,O'']f \neq 0$.
Denoting the three center of mass coordinates $X$, $Y$, and $Z$, and the sole triplet of relative coordinates $\mathbf{r} = \left(x,y,z\right)$, we define a function $f$ so that
$$
f(X,Y,Z;x,y,z) = f(Z;\mathbf{r}) = e^{iZ} \left(R^y_Z \left(Z\right) \mathbf{\hat{z}}\right) \cdot \mathbf{r}
$$
where $R^a_\phi$ denotes a rotation by an angle $\phi$ about the $a$ axis.
We define the local rotation so that
$$
R'\left(Z\right) = R^y_Z R^z_{-\pi/2} R^y_{-Z}
$$
If we set the two masses to be equal then the kinetic energy operator $T$ has the form
$$
\frac{1}{m} \left( \sum_{i = X,Y,Z} \partial_i^2 + \sum_{i = x, y, z} \partial_i^2 \right)
$$
The second derivatives with respect to the relative coordinates will annihilate $f$, and we also have
$$
O''f = e^{iZ} \left( R^y_Z \mathbf{\hat{z}} \right) \cdot \left( R'(Z) \mathbf{r} \right) = e^{iZ} \left( R^y_Z R^z_{\pi/2} R^y_{-Z} R^y_Z \mathbf{\hat{z}} \right) \cdot \mathbf{r} = f
$$
so that
$$
[\sum_{i = x, y, z} \partial_i^2, O'']f = 0
$$
So if we can show $[\sum_{i=X,Y,Z}\partial_i^2,O'']f = [\partial_Z^2,O'']f \neq 0$ then it follows that $[T,O'']f \neq 0$ and thus $[T,O''] \neq 0$.
To this end we note that
$$
\partial_Z^2 f = 2\left( i g - f\right)
$$
where
$$
g(Z;\mathbf{r}) = e^{iZ} \left( R^y_Z \mathbf{\hat{x}} \right) \cdot \mathbf{R}
$$
i.e. $g$ is obtained from $f$ by a substitution $\mathbf{\hat{z}} \to \mathbf{\hat{x}}$.
We already noted that $O'' f = f$, while for $g$ we have
$$
O''g = e^{iZ} \left( R^y_Z R^z_{\pi / 2} R^y_{-Z} R^y_Z \mathbf{\hat{x}} \right) \cdot \mathbf{r} = e^{iZ} \left( R^y_Z \mathbf{\hat{y}} \right) \cdot \mathbf{r} \equiv h
$$
so while
$$
\partial_Z^2 O'' f = \partial_Z^2 f = 2( i g - f )
$$
we on the other hand have
$$
O'' \partial_Z^2 f = 2 O'' \left( i g - f \right) = 2 \left( i h - f \right) 
$$
so that
$$
[ T, O'' ]f = \frac{2i}{m} \left( g - h \right) \neq 0 
$$
Note that we have the commutator fails to vanish even for a local rotation function $R'(Z)$ that remains for all $Z$ in the same conjugacy class $\cong \pi / 2$.
